# App class and MainWindow class relationship

Tags: wpf

In a WPF project, what kind of relationship MainWindow class has with App class? the reason I'm asking is because in a project designed base on MVVM, I do see some tasks which could be handled by MainWindows.xaml.cs or its code behind instead are implemented in App class.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MainWindow is usually connected to the `App` class through `StartupUri` in App.xaml.

You could remove the `StartupUri` in App.xaml and override `OnStartup` in App.xaml.cs like this

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    var mainWindow = new MainWindow();
    mainWindow.DataContext = <your datacontext>
    mainWindow.Show();
}
```

Comment: I agree with khellang, anytime someone does MVVM the usually have a starting window and a starting ViewModel and those are usually created and connected using the datacontext in the OnStartup override.

Comment: Thanks again ... any idea (URL?) where I can get more into its details and how they get hooked?

Comment: I guess you can find some info in the [MSDN documentation of the `Application.Startup` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.startup(v=vs.100).aspx). Another alternative is to decompile `PresentationFramework.dll` and see for yourself - there is a lot of snacks in there :)